# file transfer to client machine in springboot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot ...  How to push file to client machine based on IP address  ? I have to transfer file from my server machine to all subscribe client machine . Can any one help me ? .
Thank you in advance

Comment: This question is very broad. How exactly do the clients subscribe to the server? Do they maintain a permanent connection? Do they poll regularly for data? Have you direct access to the clients at all? Remember, a lot of ISPs use NAT, so you cannot reach any clients there from the server.

Comment: I'm new in spring boot  .. My aim is to forward  file to client machine

Comment: Still not clear what you want to do. Forward the file from where?

Comment: lets consider we have a patch of particular software this patch need to forwarded to each client machine who has this software installed ...... I'm planning to use ftp to upload file  and allow user to download  that patch of  software.. is this possible .....  Thank you for your response